# Godaddy Codesigning Certificate Convert spc to PFX

Tags: windows, certificate, godaddy, mmc

I have used [this link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/java-code-signing-generate-a-csr-4780) to create a CSR for [GoDaddy](https://in.godaddy.com) code signing  (done in Linux environment though)

- I  got the `spc` file from Goddady
- Followed their [documentation](https://in.godaddy.com/help/signtool-sign-windows-code-with-a-code-signing-certificate-4778)
- Creating the `pfx` file as per their [documentation](https://in.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698)
- Downloading the certificate and installing it
- MMC works but after that the things doesnt go as described there.

What we have is PKCS7 and to follow the documentation we need a PKCS12, the options are shaded out at
[exporting the certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Xin.jpg)

Can anyone suggest me the proper steps to do this and generate a `pfx` and then do code signing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generate p12 file from keystore file using keytool

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore E:\path\mycodesignstore -srcstorepass yourpassword -srckeypass password -destkeystore E:\path\filename.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias mycodesigncert -deststorepass password -destkeypass password
2. Fetch private key from p12 file using openssl:

   openssl pkcs12 -in E:\path\filename.p12 -passin pass:password -nocerts -out E:\path\filename.key -passout pass:password
3. Convert private key file to pvk file:

   openssl rsa -in E:\path\filename.key -outform PVK -pvk-strong -out E:\path\filename.pvk
4. Generate pfx file from spc and pvk file:

   pvk2pfx.exe -pvk E:\path\filename.pvk -pi password -spc E:\path\yourspcfile-SHA2.spc -pfx E:\path\filename.pfx -po password -f
5. Sign the exe file pfx file:

   SignTool sign /f E:\path\filename.pfx /p password /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 E:\path\yourexe_to_sign.exe

Comment: `pvk2pfx` docs can be found here. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pvk2pfx. It's a tool which is part of the Windows SDK.